# Accessing Frameset Elements

Tags: jquery

Searched the site relative to this question but didn't find what I was looking for.

I have a frameset with two child frames.
I have a list of links in the left frame and a div with the id "myDiv" in the right frame.

Using jQuery, when I mouseover a link in the left fame, how can I use the .load() method to load the "myDiv" that is in the right frame?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would be helpful if you put your html here

Comment: Not an answer, but is there a reason you have to use a frameset?  They're depreciated in HTML5, and there are cleaner and easier ways...

Comment: Please post the HTML and current javascript.  Putting it in http://jsfiddle.net/ would help too.

Comment: Solved it using plain JavaScript: parent.frameName.location. No need for loading a div or any jQuery.  Yeah, using frameset is a lousy solution here but this is an old legacy app and is not slated for refactoring just yet.  Thanks all.